# What is the best way to add model in a collection from view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette app with Router and a Controller. In my app you can view a collection of texts (index route with collection fetching from server), can view existing collection of texts (indexPage route without fetching from server) and can create a new text (form route). Views of list texts and create form are different from each other and changes in region.

I want to add a successully saved model to a collection and then redirect to indexPage route, but what is the best way to get a texts collection from _FormView success callback? Or how to restruct an app to do it simple?

I can send event to a controller with Backbone.Radio but want to deal without it.

Routes

```
router.processAppRoutes(controller, {
    '': 'index',
    'index': 'indexPage',
    'create': 'form'
});
```

Controller

```
_Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.list = new _MainTexts();
    },
    index: function () {
        if (!_.size(this.list)) {

            var
            self = this;

            this.list.fetch({

                success: function (collection, response, options) {
                    self.indexPage();
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        this.indexPage();
    },
    indexPage: function () {

        var
        textsView = new _TextsView({
            collection: this.list
        });
        application.getRegion('contentRegion').show(textsView);
    },
    form: function () {

        var
        formView = new _FormView({
            model: new _MainText()
        });
        application.getRegion('contentRegion').show(formView);
    }
});
```

Views

```
_TextView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    className: 'item text',
    template: function (serialized_model) {
        return _.template('<p><%= texts[0].text %></p>')(serialized_model);
    }
});

_TextsView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    className: 'clearfix',
    childView: _TextView
});
```

Form view

```
_FormView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#form-template',
    ui: {
        text: 'textarea[name="text"]',
        submit: 'button[type="submit"]'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.submit': 'submitForm'
    },
    submitForm: function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        this.model.set({

            text: this.ui.text.val()
        });

        this.model.save({}, {
            success: function (model, response, options) {

                ???
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: "*can view existing collection of texts (indexPage route without fetching from server) and can create a new text (form route)"*...  I'm not sure whether these are questions or statements... *"Views of list texts and create form are different from each other and changes in region."*  list texts... create form... I've no idea what these are. Could you please read this question from the perspective of someone who has no idea about your application and rephrase the question accordingly..?

Comment: @TJ Ok, maybe I put the question somewhat chaotically, but I'am already find solution. Post solution a little bit later.

Comment: Note: "The Controller object is deprecated. Instead of using the Controller
class with the AppRouter, you should specify your callbacks on a plain Javascript object or a Marionette Object"
- http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.controller.html

Comment: @misantronic Thanks for note, I did not detect deprecated warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my problem solution is here. In controller action "form" I create event listener

```
var
formView = new _FormView({

    model: model
});

formView.on('formSave', function (model) {

    if (id == null) {

        self.list.add(model);
    }

    ...
});
```

Then in form view I trigger event

```
this.model.save({}, {

    success: function (model, response, options) {

        if (response.state.success) {

            self.trigger('formSave', model);
        }
    }
});
```

That's all:)